# Turning off/disabling white flickering line on LCD monitor

Tags: display, lcd

Out of the blue yesterday while I was watching a video a white flickering line appeared on my monitor. It starts at around maybe 2-3 pixels on the right side and goes down to what looks like 1 pixel on the left.

I know it is not my GPU or the DVI cable going to the monitor because this line is still flickering on the monitor when it displays the ASUS logo prior to displaying any input.

My question is this, is there a way that I can turn off/disable the row somehow?
I'd rather have a thin solid black strip than a flickering white line, it's far less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with your monitor.

If it is showing up when it is only showing the ASUS logo then it isn't anything to do with you computer it's self. The best answer I can give you is replace it